# Creating a stand alone script to auto generaterate a google form, possibly a QR code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I am trying to create a script that will take student name, assignment, and status (checked-out, checked-in, Returned to Student) to create a URL for a pre-filled Google form.  Data would look like this

```
    A1               B1            C1
    Student name   Assignment     Status
    Kevin          Test 1         Check-out
    Bob            Test 2         Check-in
    Stan                          Returned
```

I want to create a URL for each assignment for each student for each status. Saying that when I add an assignment to the table the script will spit out an URL for pre-filled form for each status. So if I added Test 3 then I would get pre-filled (kevin, test 3, In)(Kevin, Test 3, Out)(Kevin, Test 3, Returned)... and so on for each student.

I eventually want to turn these into a pre-filled auto submit URL that is part of a QR code. That way I can put the QR code on their assignments and scan it when they get it, scan a different one when it comes back, and then a third when I return it to them. That way it is quick and easy just a scan and move on. I don't know where to start.

Been working with this:

```
  /* Use Form API to generate pre-filled form URLs
  */
  function QRGenerater() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();  // Data for pre-fill

    var formUrl = ss.getFormUrl();             // Use form attached to sheet
    var form = FormApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/formsd/15ssivqvdynjvrYxRApsWyLf10qSgrhM5VRyjqZdYxCQ/edit#");
    var items = form.getItems();

    // Skip headers, then build URLs for each row in Sheet1.
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++ ) {
      // Create a form response object, and pre-fill it
      var formResponse = form.createResponse();

      // Prefill Name
      var formItem = items[0].asListItem();
      var response = formItem.createResponse(data[i][1]);
      formResponse.withItemResponse(response);

      // Prefill Assignment
      var formItem = items[1].asListItem();
      var response = formItem.createResponse(data[i][2]);
      formResponse.withItemResponse(response);

     // Prefill Status
     var formItem = items[2].asListItem();
     var response = formItem.createResponse(data[i][3]);
     formResponse.withItemResponse(response);


     // Get prefilled form URL
     var url = formResponse.toPrefilledUrl();
      Logger.log(url);  // You could do something more useful here.  
    Logger = BetterLog.useSpreadsheet('0AkZFz57HfPamdDRhZDN0cDhSX3FQNXh3a2M0YnBXdUE');
      }
    };
```

But it doesn't quite do what I want. Just logs the URL and it is only for a pre-filled link. Also don't know how to get the link it generates to end up in a spread sheet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the script you are using is one created by Mogsdad.

To answer your last questions regarding the URL you could use

```
 range = sheet.getRange(number, number)
 var sheetwrite = sheet.setActiveRange(range)
 sheetwrite.setValue(URL);
```

Where the number,number would correspond to the row/column.

With the QR code you could just then generate a QR based on the unique URL created.